# Formatting ConvertTo-HTML report and adding count of each value as precontent

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to get "pending/failed/past due to install" KBs listing in SCCM software center from remote servers, generarting output in .csv file and converted csv file content to HTML report. Script is working fine.

**ConvertTo-HTML code which I wrote and working fine is as below:**

```
$Style =@"
<Style>
BODY{font-family:Calibro;font-size:12pt;}
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style:solid;border-color: black;border-collapse;Padding-right:5px}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;color:black;backgroud-color:#FFFFFF}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#34baed}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black}
</style>
"@
$Output = Import-Csv ".\Servers.csv"
$HTMLData = $Output|Select ServerName, LastBootedon,ArticleId,Patch,state
$Email = $HTMLData|ConvertTo-HTML -Body "<H2> SCCM Software Center Pre Scan Report. </H2>" -Head $Style -preContent "Total Servers: $TotalServers"
```

---

CSV file content:

| Servername | LastBootedon | ArticleId | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Failed |
| B | 11-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Past Due to Install |
| C | 11-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Downloaded but failed to install |
| D | 10-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Error connecting server: WMI Error |
| E | 11-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Error connecting server: WMI Error |
| F | 11-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Error connecting server: WMI Error |
| G | 10-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Failed |
| H | 11-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Past Due to Install |
| I | 11-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Downloaded but failed to install |
| J | 10-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Downloading |
| K | 11-11-2021 | KBxxxx | Pending to install |

Now I want to add count of reoccuring "State" column values in separate new line at top of the HTML report.

Desired Output what I need in HTML report:

```
SCCM Software Center Pre Scan Report

State                                  Count
Failed                                 2
Past Due to Install                    3
Downloaded but failed to install       10
WMI Error                              26
Pending to install                     6
Downloading                            1          


<HTMLCODE>
```

[image]

Comment: So... What is your question??

Comment: My Question is that I want to add count of state vaules in HTML report as a summary .  like below (As we have in Pivot table)

Total Server: 60
Failed 2 
Past Due to Install: 3 
Downloaded but failed to install: 10 
WMI Error 26 Pending to install: 6 
Downloading: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest building a summary from the different states and using `Format-List` on the result. Capture that as string and put in between `<pre>..</pre>` tags so you can add this in monospaced font to the report.

<sup>P.S. The font name is `Calibri`, not `Calibro` and the csv you show doesn't have a column `Patch`</sup>

Try:

```
$Style =@"
<Style>
BODY{font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;}
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style:solid;border-color: black;border-collapse;Padding-right:5px}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;color:black;backgroud-color:#FFFFFF}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#34baed}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black}
</style>
"@
$data = Import-Csv ".\Servers.csv"

# build the summary
$states = [ordered]@{ State = 'Count' }
$data | Group-Object State | ForEach-Object { $states[$_.Name] = $_.Count }
$states['Total Servers'] = ($data.Servername | Select-Object -Unique).Count
# format this as List string and remove the colons in front of the Count
$summary = ([PsCustomObject]$states | Format-List | Out-String ).Trim() -replace '(?m)^(.+)(?<!:):( .*)$', '$1 $2'
# put the summary in between <pre>..</pre> tags into the body
$body  = "<H2> SCCM Software Center Pre Scan Report. </H2><pre>$summary</pre>"

$HTMLData = $data | Select ServerName, LastBootedon,ArticleId,Patch,State  # the csv you show doesn't have a column Patch..
$Email = $HTMLData | ConvertTo-HTML -Body $body -Head $Style
```

Your email should then look like this:

[image]

Regex details for the `-replace`:

```
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .         Match any single character that is not a line break character
      +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)           
(?<!         Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind)
   :         Match the character “:” literally
)           
:            Match the character “:” literally
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \         Match the character “ ” literally
   .         Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: Hi Theo,
Great help here, it worked as expected. 
In Summary could it be possible to replace text "Error connecting server: WMI Error" with "Servers withj WMI Error" ?

Comment: @PuneetTiwari Sure, instead of `$data | Group-Object State | ForEach-Object { $states[$_.Name] = $_.Count }` you could do: `$data | Group-Object State | ForEach-Object { $name = if ($_.Name -match 'WMI Error') {$name = 'Servers with WMI Error'} else { $_.Name } ; $states[$name] = $_.Count }`

Comment: cool.
now last query, I have a state value in csv file as "failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the server. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."    I want that if in state  value contains "WinRM cannot process the request" then in Summary the text be as "Servers with WINRM Issue" <count>". how to achieve it?

Comment: Then just change to `$data | Group-Object State | ForEach-Object { $name = if ($_.Name -match 'WMI Error') {'Servers with WMI Error'} elseif ($_.Name -match 'WinRM') {'Servers with WINRM Issue'}  else { $_.Name } ; $states[$name] = $_.Count }`

Comment: Perfect, it worked as what i wanted. Thank you so much for your help and solving my query. May I know how to mark it as your response solved my query?